# Slack API dialog.open returning 'not_authed' error in C#

Tags: c#, http-headers, slack-api, azure-bot-service

I have a bot written in C# using Azure Bot Framework. The bot works for slack channel. I'm trying to use one of the slack API method dialog.open to open a dialog in the chat after getting a trigger like button click. I'm using the code given below just for calling the API, however the only issue is I'm getting **{"ok":false,"error":"not_authed"}** as the response.

```
               using (var client = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        
                        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage())
                        {
                            request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
                            request.RequestUri = new Uri(_configuration["SlackOpenDialog"]);
                            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", ApiToken);
                            request.Content = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                            _logger.LogInformation(request.ToString());
                            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

                            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                            {
                                string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                                _logger.LogInformation("In" + _functionName + "Dialog > SlackOpenDialogPostAsync > Slack > response ----> " + result);
                                //return result;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                _logger.LogInformation("In" + _functionName + "Dialog > SlackOpenDialogPostAsync > Slack > response ----> " + response.ReasonPhrase);
                                //return null;
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Can someone tell what could be the issue, since I'm stuck with this since hours. I really need some quick help!

Answer (score 0):

You can sanity-check that the token you are using works with that method on the Slack API documentation's tester page:

https://api.slack.com/methods/dialog.open/test

Incidentally, the docs suggest that [this method is deprecated](https://api.slack.com/dialogs) and that you should look at using modals instead.

https://api.slack.com/methods/views.open